# Meaning of $\liminf h_n$ in Probability with Martingales.

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, functions, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{h_n\}$ be a sequence of extended real valued functions. In **Lemma 3.5** of *Probabilities with Martingales* Williams uses the notations $\inf h_n$ and $\liminf h_n$ in such a way as to imply these two mean *different* things. My first thought when reading these expressions (knowing they refer to functions) is that
$$\inf h_n:x\mapsto \inf\{h_n(x) : n\in\mathbb{N}\} \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \liminf h_n : x\mapsto \liminf_{n\to\infty} h_n(x),$$
but then -if I'm not mistaken- both functions would be equal.

In the lemma, Williams shows that if the $\{h_n\}$ are measurable, then so are $\inf h_n$ and $\liminf h_n$. His proof that $\lim h_n$ is measurable makes sense if I am to interpret the expression as I have explained above, but that leaves me unsure as to what $\liminf h_n$ means, even after reading (although not understanding) the proof that such function is also measuable.

***What is the meaning of $\ \liminf h_n$?***

---

[image]

Comment: Given a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_n$, put $E$ as the set of sub-sequential limits of $a_n$. Then $\liminf_n a_n = \inf E = \min E$ (since $\liminf a_n$ is in fact a sub-sequential limit of $a_n$). There is a formula for it given by $\liminf_n a_n = \sup_{n\geq 1}\inf_{k\geq n}a_k$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang yes, it is precisely due to $\liminf_n a_n = \inf E = \min E$ (this last bit requires us to work in $[-\infty,\infty]$) that I wrote in my post that $\inf\{x\in h_n(x) : n\in \mathbb{N}\} = \liminf_{n\to\infty} h_n(x)\ \ $ (:

Comment: $\inf_n h_n \neq \sup_{n\geq 1}\inf_{k\geq n} h_k$ in general

Comment: @AndrewZhang ah, I see now what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition seems quite clear to me:
$$\begin{align} \inf h_n\colon X &\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}\\ x &\mapsto \inf\{h_n(x)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\liminf h_n\colon X&\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}\\ x&\mapsto \sup\big\{\inf\{h_r(x)\mid r\geq n\}\big|n\in\mathbb{N}\big\}\end{align}$$

Let $h_n(x)=1$ for all $n\neq 0$ and let $h_0(x)=0$. Then $\forall x\in X,\; \inf h_n(x)=0$ and $\liminf h_n(x)=1$ and thus $\liminf\neq \inf$ (in fact, $\inf h_n\leq \liminf h_n$ is always true).

Maybe a more useful way of defining $\liminf$ (which is equivalent) is by $$\liminf_n h_n=\lim_n\inf\{h_r\mid r\geq n\}.$$

Comment: I see. Out of curiosity, is this notation standard?

Comment: Pretty standard and has lots of characterizations (in my opinion, easier to use and understand)